# URL with http not working

Tags: macos, http, https

I have problem with my mac. no url is working with http url and if I use https then it's working fine.

I saw this error in each browser
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I think this might be a virus because before 1-2 hour everything was fine. So please let me know if any one faced the same issue and have solution.

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to answer to such a vague question. You have to add much more details, for example your http servers configuration (the relevant parts).

Comment: I have a broadband internet connection. I have manually setup the DNS to 8.8.8.8. 
So if I open http://facebook.com then it do not work but if I try to open https://facebook.com then it is working.

This problem happen when I was downloading some videos and on the same time I have clicked on wrong download button which downloaded wrong software. That was a package of softwares like vlc, search quick. I realised that after giving the permission of download. Then I stop that installation before completion and now here is the issue

Comment: So you want to say that you replaced your working apache installation by a partially (because stopped in mid time) and now you ask yourself why it does not work any more? Well, play in your backup of the working installation and all is fine, I'd say.

Comment: I don't able to understand what is relation of apache here. I have simple mac laptop. I were trying to download a video and on same site there were some other download link which had malicious software (apache, search-quick browser extension etc.) and that package of download created the problem. I mistakenly clicked to install those software and then stop before completion. Now I don't have idea what is the relation of apache here?

Comment: Oh, I completely miss understood you here. Since this is a place to ask _programming questions_ I automatically assumed that you trying to use a local apache installation when talking about http and https. My fault, sorry. I suggest you ask on one of the sister pages, either "SuperUser" which deals with general software issues or some Mac specific page. You can see the links in the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a pf redirection (pf is the Packet Filter that comes with the recent versions of osx) with the command

```
sudo pfctl -s nat
```

If you see something like:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from en0 to any port 80 ->127.0.0.1 port 9882
```

this is a sign that your mac has been hit by an adware, which is redirecting your http traffic to an internal logger that is (luckyly) not working properly.

In this case, try the command:

```
sudo pfctl -d
```

Your http URLs should suddenly start working.

But this could probably last just until the adware sets the pf rule again.
If you check the /Library/LaunchDaemons folder you are probably seeing at least one (but perhaps many) files named somehow like com.serendipity.plist.

This (or these) are the process(es) that run in your mac under the control of launchd and put there by the adware. Check the Log console: in the system log you are going to see that process sudo-ing the pfclt redirection every 10 seconds.

Try the command

```
sudo ls -latr /Library
```

you may also find at least one executable in the /Library folder created at the same time of two other innocently named files, often a .dat and a .zip file. That executable is probably the culprit.

Now: if you feel comfortable with Unix you now probably know enough to eradicate the adware (not an easy task but challenging and instructive, believe me!) ; if you got lost somewhere in the middle of my explanation you should look for some expert advice or make a fresh installation or make a restore from a reliable backup.

Good luck